# The name "collision" does not exist in the current context, Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

*I'm new to unity so please excuse dumbness*

When I try to start the game, I get the error message: "The name "collision" does not exist in the current context" which makes no sense as it's an in build function (I think, I have no idea)
Here's my the code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        grounded = true;
}
```

The error refers to the "collision.gameObject.tag"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your name collision should match the name given in the line above within the parentheses, in your case "other". So you can change either the word *collision* to *other*, or you can change the word *other* to *collision*. They just need to be the same thing.

*Collision2D other* is a function variable. You can use the variable in your function by using its name.